# Find a file name that holds more than one version

Tags: powershell

I wrote something that works well for most cases. I encountered with an edge case that two files with the same name (the different is the upper and lower case) and the sane version printed, actually the version is the same so I am not suppose to print them. I did a change and now it looks ok (The `$MatcheddllFiles` is empty) but I am afraid I'm missing something and might not cover all the cases. I ran it on files with an issue (some files with the name contains more than one version) and it worked. Am I missing something? I think that I am missing a case when the names are equal (with upper and lower case) but contains different versions (checked and its not working with the `-CaseSensitive`)

Assume I got the `$dlls` first

```
foreach ($dll in $dlls) {
        $MatcheddllFiles += [PsCustomObject]@{
            DllName = $dll.BaseName 
            Version = ($dll.VersionInfo.FileVersion).Replace(',', '.')
          }
       }
```

In case `$dlls` contains two dlls with the same version with names:

> ```
> dataprivilege.configuration 
> DataPrivilege.Configuration
> ```

This will be the result:

```
$differentDllVersions = $MatcheddllFiles  |
  Select-Object -Unique -Property DllName, Version |
    Group-Object  DllName  |
      Where-Object { $_.Count -gt 1 } |
        ForEach-Object { $_.Group }
$differentDllVersions
```

> ```
> DllName                     Version   
> -------                     -------   
> dataprivilege.configuration 8.6.24.491
> DataPrivilege.Configuration 8.6.24.491
> ```

My change is to add `-CaseSensitive`

```
$differentDllVersions = $MatcheddllFiles  |
  Select-Object -Unique -Property DllName, Version |
    Group-Object  DllName -CaseSensitive  |
      Where-Object { $_.Count -gt 1 } |
        ForEach-Object { $_.Group }
$differentDllVersions
```

**Update:**
It looks like this was solve it. I replaced the `Select-Object` with `Sort-Object`, make sense?

```
$differentDllVersions = $MatcheddllFiles  |
  Sort-Object -Unique -Property DllName, Version |
   Group-Object  DllName  |
    Where-Object { $_.Count -gt 1 } |
     ForEach-Object { $_.Group }
```

Comment: Is this on *nix ? Windows doesn't care about filename casing (and PowerShell is case-insensitive by default too). As aside, you should not use `$MatcheddllFiles += [PsCustomObject]@{..}` to add to an undefined variable `$MatcheddllFiles`. Instead, let PowerShell collect the data using `$MatcheddllFiles = foreach...` and inside the loop just output the PsCustomObject

Comment: Hi @Theo, I lost you
Did you understand what I need? 
Everything is working except the case I wrote. can you write your solution?

Comment: I am working on Windows

Comment: First I am using foreach, I need the PsCustomObject to show the file name and his version  only when there results (same file name shares 2 versions)

Comment: This helped me 
https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/12059

Comment: **1st** Please [edit] your question to improve your [mcve]. In particular, share how do you get the `$dlls`. **2nd** Please update the question instead posting additional info in comments (no `StackExchange` site is a chat). **3rd** Please do not update question with a solution. [Self-answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have discovered yourself, you ran into a **long-standing [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) bug**, where 
**`-Unique` is unexpectedly and invariably case-*sensitive***, as of PowerShell 7.3.1.

- See [GitHub issue #12059](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/12059); a simple repro:

  ```bash
  # !! Outputs BOTH inputs, even though 'foo'
  # !! is just a case variation of 'FOO'.
  'foo', 'FOO' | Select-Object -Unique
  ```
- The *expected* behavior that would be consistent with other cmdlets, such as `Sort-Object`, `Group-Object` and `Select-Object` is:

  - Case-*insensitivity* by default.
  - Case-*sensitivity* as an *opt-in*, via a `-CaseSensitive` switch.

**Workarounds**:

- If you don't need to maintain the input order, instead using [`Sort-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object) `-Unique`, which *does* behave as expected, is a viable solution, as you've discovered.

  - Oddly, `Sort-Object -Unique` even appears to be *faster* than `Select-Object -Unique`, even though it shouldn't be - see [GitHub issue #7707](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7707).
- If you *do* want to maintain the input order, use `Select-Object -Unique` with a [*calculated property*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties), where you can case-normalize the input values.

Here's a simplified example:

```bash
@(
  [pscustomobject] @{ DllName = 'FOO'; Version = '1.2.3.4' }
  [pscustomobject] @{ DllName = 'foo'; Version = '1.2.3.4' }
) |
  Select-Object -Unique -Property @{ 
      Name='DllName'; Expression={ $_.DllName.ToLower() }
    },
    Version
```

Output:

```
DllName Version
------- -------
foo     1.2.3.4
```

Note how the two input objects resulted in only *one* output object, because the lowercased version of the `.DllName` property values (as well as the `.Version` values) matched.

However, the output objects' `.DllName` property will invariably contain the lowercased value.

---

By contrast, `Sort-Object -Unique` *preserves* the original case (and by definition *sorts* by the specified properties); in *[PowerShell (Core) 7+](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) only*, you can add `-Stable` to predictably use the *first* among the duplicates:

```bash
@(
  [pscustomobject] @{ DllName = 'FOO'; Version = '1.2.3.4' }
  [pscustomobject] @{ DllName = 'foo'; Version = '1.2.3.4' }
) | 
  Sort-Object -Unique DllName, Version # PSv7+: add -Stable, if needed.
```

Output:

```bash
DllName Version
------- -------
FOO     1.2.3.4
```

Comment: Hi @mklement0
I have the same issue in a different function and I get errors when I replaced the select-object with sort-object. how can I solve this?


Get-ChildItem -Path $tempFolder -File  -Recurse -Exclude filesSources.txt, vip.manifest, '*Content_Types*.xml'  | 
        Sort-Object @{Name = 'SourceArchive'; Expression = { $file.FullName } },
        @{Name = 'FileName'; Expression = { $_.Name } } -Unique

Comment: Sort-Object : The Name key is not valid.
At line:775 char:9
+         Sort-Object @{Name = 'SourceArchive'; Expression = { $file.Fu ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Sort-Object], NotSupportedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DictionaryKeyIllegal,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SortObjectCommand

Comment: $MatchedSourceFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $tempFolder -File  -Recurse -Exclude filesSources.txt, vip.manifest, '*Content_Types*.xml'  | 
        Select-Object @{Name = 'SourceArchive'; Expression = { $file.FullName } },
        @{Name = 'FileName'; Expression = { $_.Name } } -Unique

############################################
$result = $MatchedSourceFiles | Group-Object FileName  | Where-Object { $_.Count -gt 1 } | ForEach-Object { $_.Group }

Comment: @Bandit, you cannot rename properties while sorting; use a separate `Select-Object` call for renaming. Your sort command should be `Sort-Object { $file.FullName }, Name -Unique`

Comment: Can you show me please where should I need to replaced it? in which part?
Thanks

Comment: @Bandit, code in comment is hard to read. I assume you're looking for the following; if that doesn't help, please ask a _new_ question: `Get-ChildItem -Path $tempFolder -File -Recurse -Exclude filesSources.txt, vip.manifest, 'Content_Types.xml' | 
Select-Object @{Name = 'SourceArchive'; Expression = 'FullName' }, @{Name = 'FileName'; Expression = 'Name' }
Sort-Object SourceArchive, FileName -Unique`

Comment: Thanks @mklement0. should be '|'?      ...  | Sort-Object SourceArchive, FileName -Unique

Comment: @Bandit, yes, I forgot the `|` before `Sort-Object` - sorry.